# Is there a Scheme implementation that parallelizes?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme, parallel-processing, language-implementation

Is there a R5RS-or-higher Scheme implementation that does parallelization?  For example, if I say to do:

```
(map (lambda (x) 
        (pure-functional-stuff x))
     '(1 3 5 7 11 13))
```

it will process 1, 3, 5, and 7 simultaneously if the machine can do it?  That's supposed to be one of the big advantages of functional programming, but I can't find a maintained, up-to-date Scheme that does it.  I'd be fine with one that wouldn't parallelize it unless I assert that the function doesn't have side-effects.

Comment: Automatic parallelization is still rarely seen. If some FP enthusiast says FP language programs are 'better to parallelize', then he/she probably means by 'you', the programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a developer of Schemik and I think that it is the Scheme you are looking for. The project is still developed and maintained. Early this year, I released a version which improves compatibility with R5RS. Unfortunately, Schemik is a research project focused on the process of expression evaluation, thus, its standard library is still relatively small. Is there any particular functionality you miss in Schemik?

Comment: I'm digging into it now.  I don't know for sure yet, but it looks promising.

Comment: It does what I need for right now --- thanks!  I've been wanting to try something that works this way.

Answer (score 3):

[Racket](http://racket-lang.org) has [futures](http://pre.plt-scheme.org/docs/html/reference/futures.html) that do something very similar to this, and will also have a second approach for parallelism in the near future (which will be called "places").

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that you don't really want the compiler to try to parallelize *everything* because then you end up wasting time coordinating efforts even when doing something simple like,

```
(map add1 '(1 2 3))
```

that would be faster to just do on one thread. However, many functional languages these days make it easy for you to make this parallel when "add1" is actually "really-long-computation". Each language has its own approach, but I'd recommend taking advantage of multiple cores in Racket using futures.

While the compiler deciding things automatically for you is nice, it's not a bad tradeoff to change a "map" to a "pmap" where you think it might help rather than deal with slowdowns in other places because the compiler was too ambitious.

Something as basic as

```
(define (pmap f xs)
  (map touch (map (λ(x) (future (λ() (f x)))) xs)))
```

can get you pretty far when used judiciously, but you should experiment with chunking up your data to feed to parallel threads.

Answer (score 2):

I just found Schemik

http://schemik.sourceforge.net/

which seems to be maintained to at least 2009, though I don't know if it's R5RS.

Comment: It confuses me that it claims to be a "dialect of Scheme and Common Lisp".  Do they mean, "a dialect of Lisp"?

Comment: It does approach R5RS, though I had to dig through commit comments to find that out.  Seriously underdocumented, as a whole, and it has a bus factor of 1, but it has potential.